# Random effects from Intercepts and Slopes as Outcomes model

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

I am trying to reproduce with R the results from Intercepts- and Slopes-as Outcomes model from *Hierarchical Linear Models* by Raudenbush and Bryk, which deals with High School and Beyond dataset.

[Model and results from Raudenbush book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI96N.png)

The `hsb` dataset comes from the `mlmhelpr` package and my R code is:

```r
library(lme4)
library(mlmhelpr)

hsb=hsb
groupMeanses = aggregate(hsb$ses, list(hsb$id), FUN = mean, data=hsb)
names(groupMeanses) = c('id','groupMeanses')
hsb = merge(hsb, groupMeanses, by = c('id'))
hsb$ses_centered_a = (hsb$ses - hsb$groupMeanses)
hsb$ses_centered_b = (hsb$ses - hsb$meanses)

M3d = lmer(mathach ~ 1 + ses_centered_b * meanses + ses_centered_b * catholic 
      + (1+meanses|id) , REML = F, data=hsb, 
      control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", boundary.tol = 1e-5))

summary(M3d)
```

and the results from it:

[R lme4 code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv81h.png)

As you can see, both results (those from Raudenbush and Bryk book and my R code) look pretty close, except for the random effects. I found a tutorial on Internet that fits the same model using HLM 6 that reproduces the results correctly, so I must be doing something wrong in R.

[HLM6 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EvfD.png)

**My question is**: what modification should I do in my code or what is the right way in R to get the right results?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be absolutely sure, but my best guess is that the various packages in R (I tried several; see below) are coming up with *better* fits to the data than HLM6. In particular, the HLM6 output you list reports a deviance (in this case, -2 times the log-likelihood) of 46501.875643; several different R packages report deviances of 46497.4 (about 4.4 deviance units lower). Lower deviances are better, so it seems that R's fits are actually better.

In a little more detail: I fitted the same model with `lme4::lmer`, `nlme::lme`, and `glmmTMB::glmmTMB`, which all implement mixed model fitting in (slightly) different ways.  They all found *singular fits*, with small or minimal slope standard deviations (from 6e-6 to 0.05), highly variable correlation between slopes and intercepts (which makes sense — as the slope SD goes to zero, the slope-intercept correlation becomes undefined). The deviances and estimates of intercept SD and residual SD were highly consistent.

```r
  package sd.(Intercept)           cor   sd.meanses sd.Observation deviance
1    lmer       1.520733 -1.0000000000 5.341325e-02       6.062259 46497.41
2     lme       1.520815 -0.0001895723 2.457569e-03       6.062254 46497.44
3 glmmTMB       1.520813  0.9723940794 5.643373e-06       6.062255 46497.44
```

I also used the `allFit()` function to try a wide range of optimizers within `lmer` - these all gave consistent answers.

The next test would be to take the estimates from HLM6, evaluate the log-likelihoods from the various R packages (this is fairly straightforward with `lmer` and `glmmTMB`), and see if we recover the HLM6 deviance estimate. Unfortunately, HLM6 doesn't appear to report the intercept-slope covariance (or correlation).

```r
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(glmmTMB)

M3d = lmer(mathach ~ 1 + ses_centered_b * meanses + ses_centered_b * catholic 
      + (1+meanses|id) , REML = FALSE, data=hsb, 
      control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", boundary.tol = 1e-5))

M3e = glmmTMB(mathach ~ 1 + ses_centered_b * meanses + ses_centered_b * catholic 
      + (1+meanses|id) , REML = FALSE, data=hsb)

M3f = lme(mathach ~ 1 + ses_centered_b * meanses + ses_centered_b * catholic,
          random = ~ 1+meanses|id , method = "ML", data=hsb)


library(broom.mixed)
library(tidyverse)

fitlist <- list(lmer = M3d, lme = M3f, glmmTMB = M3e)

(fitlist
    |> purrr::map_dfr(tidy, effect = "ran_pars", .id = "package")
    |> select(package, term, estimate)
    |> mutate(across(term, ~gsub("_+",".", .)))
    |> mutate(across(term, ~gsub("cor.*", "cor", .)))
    |> pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate")
    |> mutate(deviance = c(deviance(fitlist$lmer), deviance(fitlist$lme), 2*M3e$obj$fn()))
    |> as.data.frame()
)

aa <- allFit(M3d)

(tidy(aa, effect = "ran_pars")
    |> select(optimizer, term, estimate)
    |> pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate")
    |> as.data.frame()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code fixes the issue of boundary (singular) fit and also the variance components look more informative:

```
library(lme4)
library(mlmhelpr)

hsb=hsb

groupMeanses <- aggregate(hsb$ses, list(hsb$id), FUN = mean, data=hsb)
names(groupMeanses)<- c('id','groupMeanses')
hsb <- merge(hsb, groupMeanses, by = c('id'))

hsb$ses_centered_a = (hsb$ses - hsb$groupMeanses)

M3h2 = lmer(mathach ~ 1 + ses_centered_a * meanses 
            + ses_centered_a * catholic       
            + (1+ses_centered_a|id), 
            REML = T, data=hsb)

summary(M3h2)
```

Apart from fitting the model with REML, the improved code uses the **ses** column centered around its high school mean (**ses_centered_a**), instead of **ses** centered around **meanses** (**ses_centered_b**), both for the fixed effects and random effects. Furthermore, in the R code that originated the current question, the **meanses** column was used in the random effects part, not **ses_centered_a** as stated before.

[image: new code]

Comment: Other than using REML=TRUE, can you explain what you did differently so we don't have to hunt through the code/compare and figure it out for ourselves? This still doesn't match HLM6 exactly, although it's much closer (e.g., deviance is off by 2 units, slope variance is off by 0.05) (FWIW, [the tutorial that I think the OP is referring to](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/hlm/hlm-mlm/introduction-to-multilevel-modeling-using-hlm/) does use REML rather than ML ...

Comment: OK.  Can you edit your answer to include this information?